# Align leaders to the right end of the enclosing hbox?

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, plain-tex, leaders

Suppose I have an alignment with two columns of centered text. How can I add a `\dotfill` between these two columns?
If I do this

```
\vbox{\halign{%
  \hfil#\leaders\hbox to 5pt{\hfil.\hfil}\hskip 20pt plus 1 fil%
    &\leaders\hbox to 5pt{\hfil.\hfil}\hfil#\hfil\cr%
  abc&defgh\cr%
  a&b\cr%
  abc&d\cr%
}}
```

I will get a random extra space between the dots at the border of the two columns, because the two adjacent `\leaders` commands each align to the left end of their enclosing hbox.

Is there a way to

- have halign use multiples of a specified unit for the column width,
- have `\leaders` (or maybe `\cleaders`) aligned to the right end of the enclosing hbox, or
- align leaders to an outer hbox rather than the directly enclosing hbox?

I know that I could work around the problem by using fixed-width columns rather than halign.

Comment: @CroCo The code compiles if you add `\bye` to the end and compile in `pdfTeX`.

Comment: @CroCo: It's plain TeX, so just use `tex` or `pdftex`...

Comment: I didn't pay attention to `plaint-tex` tag, sorry for inconvenience. I've removed my comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way would be to set the data twice, after the first setting measure the width of the first column, and then re-set forcing the first column to be a multiple of 5pt wide, rounding up the natural width. I added a `,` to your example as it maximised the gap at the cell boundary, as shown in the first alignment.

[image]

```
\vbox{\halign{%
  \hfil#\leaders\hbox to 5pt{\hfil.\hfil}\hskip 20pt plus 1 fil%
    &\leaders\hbox to 5pt{\hfil.\hfil}\hfil#\hfil\cr%
  abc&defgh\cr%
  a&b\cr%
  ab,c&d\cr%
}}

\bigskip
\tracingonline1

\setbox0\vbox{%
\global\setbox1\vbox{}%
\halign{%
  \hfil#\hskip 20pt plus 1 fil%
    &\hfil#\hfil\cr%
  abc&defgh\cr%
  a&b\cr%
  ab,c&d\cr%
}
\setbox0\lastbox
\setbox0\hbox{\unhbox0\unskip\setbox0\lastbox\unskip}%
\count0=\wd0
\divide\count0 327680
\multiply\count0 5
\ifdim\count0 pt<\wd0
\advance\count0 5
\fi
\xdef\colwidth{\the\count0 pt}%
}
\vbox{
\halign{%
  \hbox to\colwidth{\hfil#\leaders\hbox to 5pt{\hfil.\hfil}\hskip 20pt plus 1 fil}%
    &\leaders\hbox to 5pt{\hfil.\hfil}\hfil#\hfil\cr%
  abc&defgh\cr%
  a&b\cr%
  ab,c&d\cr%
}
}

\bye
```